# Converting an address into geopoint

Tags: android, google-maps

I want the user to enter the location he wants to search for places that are near by using google places api.I want to know how to convert the string into geopoints?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do so by simply calling getFromLocationName()

```
Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());     
 try {
        List<Address> address = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(locationName, 1);    
        double latitude = address.get(0).getLatitude();
        double longitude = address.get(0).getLongitude();            
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `android.location.Geocoder` class in Android to get the lat/lon. Check out the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html

If you prefer an external API, you can use the Google Geocoding API for the same. The documentation is over here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Check out this thread for more information/usage: [Android geopoint from location/locality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167819/android-geopoint-from-location-locality)