# Android: Get directions from Google Map V2 providing address

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I'm trying to get direction from my location to the provided address in android Google map v2, for that I'm using following code.

```
String daddr = AddressLine1() + " " + AddressLine2() + " " + City() + " " + Pincode();
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + "" + "&daddr=" + daddr));
                    startActivity(i);
```

in above code "saddr=" its blank, so its always takes current location but in "daddr=" is taking partial address, like if the address is `"Dcusa Inc, US Highway 22, Mountainside, NJ, United States"`, its will takes only `"Dcusa Inc, "` this much and ask autocomplete. But I want to take full address. I've debug the code before sending daddr data to activity its showing full address. I don't know what to do now, please help me how can I trigger it..

Answer (score 1):

Direcly you cant do that. First you have to get the latitude and longitude of the source and destination address.You can refer the below mentioned link to get co-ordinates. 
[TO Get geopoints using address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10167819/android-geopoint-from-location-locality)

From this reference you will get latitude and longitude and you can pass the values to maps url using intent.
then it will work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=xx.xx,xx.xx&daddr=xx.xx,xx.xx"));
            startActivity(intent);
```

here xx.xx means latitude and longitude.

Comment: you should not left the source address blank.You have to give your current location latitude and longitude also get the latitude and longtitude of destination addres by using "To Get geopoint" link.Pass both value to intent.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because of space. 
You need to URL encode the address string as it will be a parameter in the maps URL to be valid